# why isn't my useEffect navigate not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a sign-up form but my use effect is not working. There are no errors and my mentor says it should work. We are kind of stuck on this bug. Please help. Everything else works including the rejection event. The fetch data works. It shows up as the JSON data.

```
const SignupPage = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    function errormessage(){
        return 'something went wrong'
    }
//---------------------------------------------

const errorDiv = useRef('')
const [error,errorUpdate] = useState(null)

//-------------------------------------------------
    async function FormSubmit(){
        const emailInput = document.getElementById('email')
        const passwordInput = document.getElementById('password')
        const email = emailInput.value
        const password = passwordInput.value
        const button = document.getElementById('button')
    
    
       try{
    
        button.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
            event.preventDefault()
        })
    
        const Options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({email:email,password:password})
        }
    
        const fetchUserCreate = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/Signup',Options)

    
        const jsonData = await fetchUserCreate.json()

        jsonData.catch(error=>{
            return PromiseRejectionEvent
        })

        useEffect(()=>{
        if(jsonData.ok){
            return navigate('/')
        }
        },[jsonData])

        //console.log(jsonData)
       } catch (error) {
        errormessage()
        errorUpdate(errormessage())
       
        
       }
    
    }



    return ( 
        <div className="container">
            <div className="black"></div>
            <video src={SnowVid} type="video/mp4" autoPlay muted loop id='video1'></video>
            <div id="login-container">
                <h2 className="title-galixy">I0I</h2>
                <div id="Signup">
                <b><h2 className="title-card">Signup</h2></b>
                {/* ---------------------------- */}

                    <i><h3 className="email">Email</h3></i>
                    <div className="input"><input name='email' id='email' type="text" className="inputs" /></div>

                    
                    <i><h3 className="Password">Password</h3></i>
                    <div className="input"><input name='Password' id='password' type="text" className="inputs" /></div>
                    <div className="error" ref={errorDiv} >{error}</div>

                    <div className="button"><button onClick={()=>{FormSubmit()}} className='LastButton' id='button'><b>Login</b></button></div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
```

k

```
        useEffect(()=>{
        if(jsonData.ok){
            return navigate('/')
        }
        },[jsonData])
```

I wanted it to navigate to / if jsonData is not an error. It is my signup page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code:

1. [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is suppose to be outside of the scope of FormSubmit function. It should be in the scope of the component's render phase. (right before the declaration of FormSubmit function)
2. You should call the [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) function from the event that FormSubmit is getting.
3. Instead of getting the input values from the global document, get them by extracting the values from the form event.
   You can use `<form onSubmit={(event) => FormSubmit(event)} />`, or with
   `<button type="submit" onClick={(event) => FormSubmit(event)}/>` for getting it.

**Side notes:**

- I would remove jsonData.catch; you already catch the error inside the catch phase.
- If you want to navigate to `'/'` when you are getting the data, you can call `navigate('/')` immediately when you are getting the required data.
- Another option would be to use the useEffect outside of the scope of this function - to lift it up to the wrapper component scope. (SignupPage)
  Notice that if you are deciding to lift the useEffect up - you would have to use another state that will trigger the useEffect properly.

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [error, errorUpdate] = useState("");
  const [shouldNavigate, setShouldNavigate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldNavigate) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [shouldNavigate]);

  async function FormSubmit() {
    const emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
    const passwordInput = document.getElementById("password");
    const email = emailInput.value;
    const password = passwordInput.value;

    try {
      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }),
      };

      const fetchUserCreate = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:5000/Signup",
        options
      );

      const jsonData = await fetchUserCreate.json();
      if (jsonData.ok) {
        setShouldNavigate((prev) => !prev);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      errorUpdate(error?.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to call navigate('/') immediately after you receive the data inside the FormSubmit function.

If you want to experiment with useEffect - take the code snippet I added to my answer :)

Comment: it dosent work it navigate even when i only want it to send error

Comment: You said you want it to navigate when you are not receiving any errors... Please clarify what do you want the code to do :/

Comment: I want it to navigate when the server says it info is correct but give error when info isnt correct. the code you gave me navigates at all times even with error on my end

Comment: You are sending from the server fulfilment to the client even if the 'info' is not as you want? So just add if codition if(jsonData.ok) around the setShouldNavigate.

Comment: it gives error it says jsondata not defined but when i put it near the json data it dosent do the use effect

Comment: Try to re copy my code snippet, added if condition there.
For catching the error It really depends on how your server retrieves the data.

Usually, if there are any issues in the backend, it should reject the promise by throwing an error, and the client should catch them in the catch phase.

However, if you are expecting to receive fulfilled promise, you can add more if conditions after fetching the data.

Comment: just copied it and pasted right now it litteraly did nothing not even kidding and not trying to be mean